# Is there a command line tool to shrink partition size?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, software-recommendation, partitioning, gparted

I have searched around and found [this page](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html). But is GUi tool.

IS there a command line tool I can use to shrink one of my partition size

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0009b200

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    60158297    30078125   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       616775678   625141759     4183041    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda3        60160000   616773631   278306816   83  Linux
/dev/sda5       616775680   625141759     4183040   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I would like to resize /dev/sda1 partition

Answer (score 3):

As /dev/sda1 is your boot partition, you are not going to want to resize it while the system is live, nor would be likely able to.

For your best bang for your buck, use GParted.  It's a dedicated distribution which boots 
to a minimal GUI specifically for resizing and moving partitions around.  It will handle all aspects of the resizing for you, including defragmenting (when moving NTFS or FAT partitions), shrinking partitions prior to a move (if required), and expanding the partition to fill the space available on the drive.